# ETS (error, trend, seasonal) formulation

Tags: forecasting, seasonality, trend, exponential-smoothing

Does someone know if there is (clever) way to formulate mathematically all the following models below:

[image]

in a unique (system) of equations?

Comment: You can of course express all of this in a single equation if you use lots of 0-1 variables that "turn off" most components in any given situation. I do not think this is very helpful. Judging that this classification was originally proposed by Gardner in 2006 ("Exponential Smoothing: The State of the Art Part II"), it seems like most of the rest of the forecasting community has agreed with my for the last 17 years.

Comment: See Equation (2.12) in my 2008 Springer book (https://robjhyndman.com/expsmooth/)

Comment: @RobHyndman Thanks a lot but may i ask you a question. May you detail me (with a maximum of steps) how from 2.12 you get for example the most bottom right ETS model from your table 2.1? Because i don't get it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

This is explained in my 2008 Springer book ([robjhyndman.com/expsmooth](https://robjhyndman.com/expsmooth)), Section 2.5.2. Here is an excerpt.

> The general model involves a state vector $\textbf{x}_t = (\ell_t, b_t,
> s_t, s_{t−1}, \dots, s_{t-m+1})'$ and state space equations of the form
> \begin{align}
> y_t = w(\textbf{x}_{t-1}) + r(\textbf{x}_{t−1})\varepsilon_t\\
> \textbf{x}_t = f (\textbf{x}_{t−1}) + g(\textbf{x}_{t−1}) \varepsilon_t,
> \end{align}
> where $\{\varepsilon_t\}$ is a Gaussian white noise process with variance $\sigma^2$, and $\mu_t = w(x_{t−1})$. The model with additive errors has $r(\textbf{x}_{t−1}) = 1$, so that $y_t = \mu_t + \varepsilon_t$. The model with multiplicative errors has $r(\textbf{x}_{t −1}) = \mu_t$, so that $y_t = \mu_t (1 + \varepsilon_t$). Thus, $\varepsilon_t = (y_t −\mu_t)/\mu_t$ is the relative error for the multiplicative model.

To give a specific example, consider the ETS(M,Ad,M) model with $m=4$. Then $\textbf{x}_t = (\ell_t, b_t, s_t, s_{t−1}, s_{t-2}, s_{t-3})'$,
$\textbf{x}_{t-1} = (\ell_{t-1}, b_{t-1}, s_{t-1}, s_{t−2}, s_{t-3}, s_{t-4})'$,
\begin{align}
w(\textbf{x}_{t-1}) = (\ell_{t-1}+\phi b_{t-1})s_{t-4} \\
r(\textbf{x}_{t-1}) = (\ell_{t-1}+\phi b_{t-1})s_{t-4} \\
f(\textbf{x}_{t-1}) = \left[\begin{array}{c} (\ell_{t-1}+\phi b_{t-1}) \\ \phi b_{t-1}\\ s_{t-4} \\ s_{t-1} \\ s_{t-2} \\ s_{t-3} \end{array}\right] \\
g(\textbf{x}_{t-1}) = \left[\begin{array}{c} \alpha (\ell_{t-1}+\phi b_{t-1}) \\ \beta(\ell_{t-1} + \phi b_{t-1}) \\ \gamma s_{t-4} \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array}\right]
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's a honor to get an answer from you. Please maybe consider adding the above example (and another one( in the next edition of your books.
Best regards